# How to customize the View of Java 9+ JTextField for different code-point of the text in its Model?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, unicode, jtextfield

All Java Swing components use MVC, for each component there is a **Controller**, **Model** and **View**. Particularly, `JTextField` uses `PlainDocument` as its model to fetch data and uses `TextUI` as its view to render the data. The link in JavaDoc : [JavaDoc JTextComponents MVC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html) .
 Usually the Data for a `JTextField` is the *text* and for each character of the text, Java uses a *code-point* and something called `GlyphView` will render them to view the text of `JtextField`. There are some characters known as ***non-printable*** (like `\u0000` in Unicode) and a `JTextField` wouldn't render them. 
I tried to change the model using `PlainDocument` to replace non-printable characters in the text string with a printable one using `replaceAll()` method of `String` :

```
protected class TextModel extends PlainDocument
{

    TextModel()
    {}

    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException
    {
        str = str.replaceAll("\u0000", "\ufffd");
        super.insertString(offs, str, a);
    }

}
```

but I don't want to do any process on String or any changes on Model. How can I change the view of the `JTextField` to render non-printable characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I said, I tried to change the model using `PlainDocument` to replace non-printable characters in the text string with a printable one using `replaceAll()` method of `String`. The first part of this approach is true, we have to extend `PlainDocument` but instead of overriding `insertString()` method, I use `getText(int offset, int length, Segment txt)` method to override it.

 *This method fetches the text contained within the given portion of the document which start from `offset` and has a specified `length`*. the `Segment` which has an array, plays the important roll. Desired change must be apply to the `Segment`. Using a shared double buffer, I could map any nonprintable character to printable one in a `JTextField` without changing its data, something like this:

```
@Override
    public void getText(int offset, int length, Segment txt) throws BadLocationException
    {
        super.getText(offset, length, txt);

        System.arraycopy(txt.array, txt.offset, sharedDoubleBuffer.array, sharedDoubleBuffer.offset, sharedDoubleBuffer.count);
         // map nonprintable characters 
        charMappingLogic(sharedDoubleBuffer);
        // set contents of the supplied buffer to that of our modified shared double-buffer
        txt.array = sharedDoubleBuffer.array;
    }
```